# Logarithm as Exponent conversion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

My textbook has a sample problem all worked out, but I don't understand how they went from one line to the next and there is NO explanation in the text.  Can anyone please help?

($\lg = \log_2$)  The conversion is:

> $$\frac{3}{4} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{\lg n} = \frac{3}{4} n^{\lg\frac{3}{4}}
> $$

All they did was switch $\frac{3}{4}$ with $n$, but I don't understand why this is valid.

Thank you in advance,

-Bond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that all of the following expressions "make sense" (i.e. the logarithms are all defined), we have
$$ a = b^{\log_b(a)} \tag{a}.$$
Indeed, this formula is often taken to be the *definition* of a logarithm base $b$ in pre-calculus classes, where more sophisticated tools are not discussed.  But then
\begin{align}
a^{\log_b(c)} &= \left( b^{\log_b(a)} \right)^{\log_b(c)} \tag{by (1), with $a = b^{\log_b(a)}$} \\
&= \left( b^{\log_b(c)} \right)^{\log_b(a)} \tag{laws of exponents} \\
&= c^{\log_b(a)}. \tag{by (1), with $c = b^{\log_b(c)}$}
\end{align}
In short, for any base $b$, we have
$$ a^{\log_b(c)} = c^{\log_b(a)}. $$
To obtain the identity in the original question, take $a = \frac{3}{4}$ and $c = n$, with base $b = 2$.  If we make these substitutions, we obtain
$$ \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^{\lg(n)} = n^{\lg(\frac{3}{4})}, $$
which, after multiplying by $\frac{3}{4}$ on each side, is the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  That really helped.  I see that Y. Forman's answer is basically the same thing, but it doesn't tell me why it works, which was my question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $b$ be the base.

$$ x^{\log y} =  (b^{\log x})^{\log y}=  (b^{\log y})^{\log x} = y^{\log x} $$